# How to enable/disable upload files button in Azure DevOps Repository toolbar

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I want to disable/ enable the Upload files button under the Repository toolbar in Azure DevOps. I would like to know how to configure the enable/disable option for repository toolbar buttons in Azure DevOps.

Comment: which buttons? i dont think you can alter azure devops ui in anyway

Comment: You can only disable it by prohibiting a user to contribute to a repo, i don't know of another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, seems you are talking about this button:

[image]

There is no way to disable/hidden this button. You could not control this UI in Azure DevOps web portal.

However, if you do not want other users to commit files in the repo, you could use **permission** to restrict them.

You can set the permissions for all Git repositories for a project, or for a single repository.

[image]

More details please take a look at our official tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions).